# how can I resize user's picture with css

Tags: 7, theming, tokens

Can someone please help with the above question, I want to display [current:user-picture] using token, which has a initial size of 100x100 and resize it to 20x20  with css. But its not working.
 I'D TRiED TO...
1. Change the image style to 20x20 but its thesame everywhere I use the token
2. «Span class='image-resize'»[current:user-picture]«/span». 
  help me out.
If you can suggest another ways to resize the picture.

Comment: A span is an inline element which does not have a height. Using a div instead should work as expected. Alternatively you can add 'display: block' or inline-block on the span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to resize an image using CSS but you'll need to make sure you're targeting the img element rather than the span. See this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ratface/pen/kJEcI).

As an alternative you could try using [ImageCache Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_token) but there is presently only a dev release and may not be that stable:

Create a new image style, admin/config/media/image-styles/add, to resize the image and then install and enable ImageCache Token to provide you with a token for that image style.